# Как сделать динамический контекст для активити

Tags: android, activity

Хочу написать программу-викторину. Варианты ответа и вопросы с Parse.com будут помещены в ListView и TextView соответственно.

Вопрос: как мне сделать так, чтобы не создавать каждое новое активити на каждый новый вопрос, а только на одном активити менять вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [фрагменты](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragments.php). Создаёте активити, и отображаете в ней фрагменты, столько сколько нужно. Можно одновременно несколько.
В статье все хорошо написано, если будут вопросы задавайте.

На картинке черная область это лэйаут активити, белая это область фрагмента, который будет меняться. Кнопка буде находиться вне фрагмента, т.е. в разметке активити и обрабатываться в самой активити. Способ отображения фрагментов сами можете выбрать.
[image: Картинка]

Comment: Спасибо. Появился вопрос, допустим, на активити кнопка по нажатию которой вызывается второй, третий и.тд фрагменты. В результате работы фрагментов нужно вывести результат тестирования. Можно это сделать?

Comment: @АлинаБайрамова я не понял.

Comment: Забудьте:) Тогда такой вопрос, можно ли по нажатию только одной и той же кнопки последовательно вызывать фрагменты. Т.е выбрал вариант ответа, нажал кнопку "Далее", а в ответ вызывается второй фрагмент со следующим вопросом, потом опять "Далее" и третий фрагмент

Comment: @АлинаБайрамова да, можно, обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Для каждого нового вопроса и ответа создавать новый фрагмент совершенно излишне и в корне неправильно . Вам надо создать один фрагмент , а затем управлять его контентом с помощью методов вроде textView.setText() и тд , обновляя содержимое одного и того же фрагмента при обработке клика на кнопке вроде "Следующий вопрос" .
Написание приложения-викторины подробно рассматривается в книге Брайна Харди , Билла Филлипса  "Программирование под Android" , 2014 г. , найти ее не составит труда .
Там же вы узнаете еще очень много всего интересного , как нужно разрабатывать приложения для андроид

вот [исходный код](https://github.com/tehras/GeoQuiz) приложения-викторины ,как видите используется всего одна активити . Подробнейший разбор , что там для чего , непосредственно в книге выше .

Comment: Спасибо большое, сама уже додумалась)
Если интересно, то сделала так же как вы сказали, только без фрагмента, вместо него использовала активити.