# Android : вопрос о активности

Tags: android

Во время создания приложения появилась необходимость "листания" одного участка страницы. Причем изначально неизвестно, сколько страниц будет доступно для "листания". Как такое осуществить? Обязательно нужно создавать несколько активностей?
[image: визуально:]

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужна одна активность . В разметке создаете виджет, например, TextView для текста , ImageView для изображения и тд. и кнопку ,При нажатии на кнопку в методе onClick() вы меняете только контент в одной и той же активности методом setText() виджета TextView или setImageDrawable() для изображения. Если нужен рабочий пример - пишите в комментарии , я напишу , только уточните , где хранятся эти "страницы" , что из себя представляют и тд . Для полного ответа недостаточно данных.
Так же смотрите этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/414355/177345)

Answer (score 0):

Для

> "листания" одного участка страницы

можно использовать фрагменты [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: Не нужно что то использовать только потому , что оно есть . Использование фрагментов в данной задаче оправдано , только если изменяемый "участок" имеет собственную логику , сложную разметку с обратной связью и тд. В остальном получится только напрасная трата ресурсов устройства.